# Merging constraints in an optimization formulation

Tags: optimization

I am having trouble merging two constraints into one in an optimization formulation. If $x\geq y\geq 0$, and $0\leq z \leq 1$, how can we add the following (merge) the following statements in the constraints:

If z=1 => x=y
If z<1 => x>y

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $z=1$ iff $x=y$?

Comment: It is not clear what type of formulation you are expecting.

Comment: A single inequality (constraint) that links the aforementioned two constraints.

Comment: You can get rid of the “ifs”, but I am not sure you will be able to get equations that satisfy KKT regularity conditions if that’s your goal.